# Не отображается код клавиш PageDown, PageUp

Tags: javascript, jquery

Собственно не отображется код клавиш PageUp, PageDown и 4 стрелки, которые находятся внизу.

```
<div id="test" tabindex="0">Click me!</div>

#test { background:red; }

$('#test').keypress(function(eventObject){ alert('Вы ввели символ с клавиатуры. Его код равен ' + event.keyCode); });
```

Сам пример кода в песочнице находится [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/zkLpytgq/)

Comment: Уж коли вы объявили аргумент как `eventObject`, то `eventObject.keyCode`, а не `event.keyCode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не отображаются, потому что ( [из источника](https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events) )

> Событие keypress возникает сразу после keydown, если нажата символьная клавиша, т.е. нажатие приводит к появлению символа.

То есть у вас даже функция не вызывается, потому что нет события. Замените `keypress` на `keydown/keyup`, если хотите, что бы несимвольные клавиши тоже ловились ( всякие `enter` )

```js
$('#test').keydown((event) => {
  alert('Вы ввели символ с клавиатуры. Его код равен ' + event.keyCode);
});
```

```css
#test {
  background: red;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" tabindex="0">Click me!</div>
```